# Controls added to FlowLayoutPanel using code don't have correct spacing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a simple form as an example.  I've added some check boxes using designer, and set the margin and padding to 0,0,0,0.  This is the form code:

```
public partial class Frm1 : Form
{
    public Frm1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AddCheckBox();
        AddCheckBox();
        AddCheckBox();

    }

    public void AddCheckBox()
    {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
        cb.Text = "AddedFromCode";
        cb.Padding = new Padding(0,0,0,0);
        cb.Margin = new Padding(0,0,0,0);
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(cb);
    }
}
```

I would expect the check boxes that are added from designer and from code to appear the same, however, they do not.

[image]

How can I get the spacing of the AddedFromCode controls to have 0 spacing?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it took me so long to figure this out.  One of the properties that designer changes when you add a control to a FlowLayoutPanel is AutoSize = true.

So in code...

```
cb.AutoSize= true;
```

solves the problem.

Comment: Actually this would be the default and what you need is `cb.AutoSize = false; ` and a line that sets the width to a common value.

Comment: Its actually not the default.  When you place a checkBox from designer, it changes the value from false (the default) to true. You can see this because immediately after placing the checkbox, the AutoSize value of True is in BOLD (indicating its changed from default).

This is the essence of the problem, because designer is automatically changing values, the developer is not familiar with what values are routinely changed from default, and the developer forgets to put those values into code.

Comment: Wow, you are right! Thanks for pointing that out!! I suggest incorporating the comment in the answer, where it is much more visible..